# Issue with jquery .animate() function and .eq()

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble animating a list of items as part of a carousel I'm working on. Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>no 1</li>
<li>no 2</li>
<li>no 3</li>
<li>no 4</li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
$('ul li').animate({left: '-=100', 1000, function(){

  $('ul li').eq(0).appendTo('ul');

});
```

Once the animation has finished the callback function is supposed to take the first list item and append it to the end of the list.

However for some reason `$('ul li').eq(0)` returns all 4 list items, instead of just the first one (which is what I was expecting). If I place this line outside of the `.animate()` function it returns just the first list item, however I need it to execute after the animation has finished which is why it's sitting within the callback function.

Any ideas why this might be happening? Been tearing my hair out over this one all day!

Answer (score 0):

It's cos the callback is firing for each `<li>`, so that's why you're getting it 4 times (well you'll get it for how ever many `<li>` items there are).

The way to do this is to make the `<li>` items float left and make the `<ul>` container a block. Then instead of animating each `<li>`, you animate the whole `<ul>` instead. That way the animation is fired only once and the callback will happen correctly.

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> If multiple elements are animated, the
>   callback is executed once per matched
>   element, not once for the animation as
>   a whole.

Here's a workaround in JS if you don't want to animate the `ul`:

```
var itemsToAnimate = $('ul li');
var callbackCount = itemsToAnimate.length;

itemsToAnimate.animate({left: '-=100'}, 1000, function(){

    if(--callbackCount > 0)
        return;

    $('ul li').eq(0).appendTo('ul');

});
```

Comment: Thanks (also to everyone who answered). Yes, that makes sense. I incorrectly thought all list items were being return when in fact the first one is being returned 4 times. Could you explain this line please? if(--callbackCount > 0)
        return;

Comment: The line you are asking about can be explained like this: **1)** Set `callbackCount` to itself -1, **2)** If `callbackCount` is above 0, abort any further execution. And if you wonder why we want to prevent further execution; the function is called as many times as there are `li` items. What you want is to have code executed just for the last `li`item, right? And that can be done by declaring a count variable, setting its start value to the number of `li` items, decreasing it by each callback and checking if the value is zero yet. It it's zero, then we've reached the last callback. Helpful? :)

Answer (score 0):

I can see some issues in your script:

1. you are starting four animations so your callback will be called four times
2. to me .appendTo('ul') seems wrong as the function accepts a jquery object not string, so it should be .appendTo($('ul'))

Make sure you are running your animation(s) as they should be.

Answer (score -1):

This is because you are calling animate to all of your `li` items, which means the `complete` function is being called 4 times, so it seems like it's returning 4 list items.  If you do it [this](http://jsfiddle.net/qyvmF/1/) way it will work.

Comment: Consideration to the animation duration is ignored

Comment: Thanks for the code, however I need to wait for the animation to finish before I append.